# Beginner hibernate: Why does my hibernate query return only one result, instead of a list?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm very new to hibernate, and I'm trying to set up a new method in our PersonDAO.

My hibernate mapping file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.foo.bar.domain">
<class name="Person" table="person">
    <meta attribute="class-description">A Person</meta>
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="rid" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>


    <version name="version" type="integer" column="rversion" unsaved-value="null" />
    <property name="UID"           type="string"  column="UID" length="16" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    <property name="lastName"         type="string"  column="last_name"  not-null="true" />
    <property name="firstName"        type="string"  column="first_name" not-null="true" />
    <property name="ownDepartment"    type="string"  column="own_department"/>

    <!-- a person has many responsibilities and a responsibility can can assigned to many person -->
    <set name="responsibilities" table="person_responsibility">
        <key column="person_id"/>
        <many-to-many column="responsibility_id" class="Responsibility"/>
    </set>

    <set name="additionalDepartments" table="PERSON_TO_ADDL_DEPARTMENT">    
        <key column="person_id"/>               
        <element column="ADDITIONAL_DEPARTMENT" type="string"/>         
    </set>                                              
</class>
```

and I've written a method like this, in java, to fetch all the managers from a given department:

```
public List<Person> getManagerByDepartment(final String givenDepartment){
    List<Person> l = (List<Person>) this.getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<Person>>() {

    public List<Person> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String query = "select p from Person p join p.responsibilities responsibilities join p.additionalDepartments additionalDepartments where responsibilities.name = 'manager' and (p.ownDepartment = :givenDepartment or additionalDepartments = :givenDepartment)";
        List<Person> result = (List<Person>) session.createQuery(query).setString("givenDepartment", givenDepartment).list();
        return result;  
        }
    });

    return l;
}
```

now I do a manual query in SQL, and I can see that for a given department, there are definitely more than one people who have the additional responsibility 'manager'...why does my method only ever return one person, instead of all of them?

I have a strong suspicion that my method, specifically my query, and not the mapping, is the issue, but I can't see what's wrong with it...

I've jumped in at the deep end here, so any help would be very much appreciated.

edit: note, I'm working on hundreds of records, not millions, and this isn't exactly a bottle-neck operation, so I'm not too worried about performance...that said if I'm doing something that's pointlessly wasteful, do point it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print hibernate query by enabling showsql option and check the query getting created and then test it against the database.

Comment: Turns out I'm stupid and neither the code nor the hibernate mapping was the issue. I was querying one database from the application, and manually connecting to an entirely different database to check what results I *should* be getting

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be sure without the sample data, but when you do `join` in HQL, it is translated to `inner join` in SQL. So, if you know that there should be more than one result with given responsibility then the problem is probably `join p.additionalDepartments`.

Try this query with `left join` for additionalDepartments and see if it works

```
String query = "select p from Person p join p.responsibilities responsibilities left join p.additionalDepartments additionalDepartments where responsibilities.name = 'manager' and (p.ownDepartment = :givenDepartment or additionalDepartments = :givenDepartment)";
```